# MySQL: check all values in a subset are in another table and output corresponding IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Store(sID, name, address, mID)
Sells(sID, pID) 
Product(pID, name, manufacturer, price)
```

I need to find which stores stock every product from a given manufacturer. For example: to search Unilever, I'd expect to return only stores which stock ALL Unilever products listed in Product, not just some of them.

I've tried lots of different queries with most being completely off the mark.

Am I right in thinking I need to create a subset of all the products made by Unilever, then somehow go through Sells and check that the list of pIDs for each sID contain all of those in the initial subset? I can then join the result with Store to get the store details.

If that's the correct logic, where would one begin?

This creates a subset of all the unilever products:

```
SELECT pID FROM Product WHERE manufacturer = "Unilever"
```

How would I then check this list against each store in Sells to find the ones that contain all the products in the list?

Comment: It's a double negative. You want to find which companies don't not sell any unilever product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to join the product table twice, once via the sells table and once directly, then use COUNT(DISTINT ...) on each joined table to check they match

```
SELECT st.*
FROM store st
INNER JOIN sells se ON st.sID = se.sID
INNER JOIN product pr1 ON se.pID = pr1.pID AND pr1.manufacturer = "Unilever"
INNER JOIN product pr2 ON pr2.manufacturer = "Unilever"
GROUP BY st.sID, 
        st.name, 
        st.address, 
        st.mID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pr1.pID) = COUNT(DISTINCT pr2.pID)
```

Comment: That has worked beautifully! I would not have thought to join the same table twice and then perform the distinct count

Comment: Not sure how well it will scale, and that will likely depend on how the number of stores, number or products and number of manufacturers relate to each other.

Comment: Just want to get everything working first, then I'll optimise later

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a Product column in Store table so that all you have to do is search for Unilever Product in the Store table. Then apply this:

```
SELECT Product FROM Store WHERE Product = "Unilever"
```

But of course you wouldnt want the column Product in your Store table so my answer cant be correct then